# Function to ignore hidden files in Python

Tags: python

I've seen other solutions to this in SO, but still am unable to get this working combined into a single-line function I want to use.

```
path = './path/to/my/folders/'

def listfolders(path):
    return [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if not f.startswith('.')]
```

Unfortunately this still returns -- among my desired folders --  a `.DS_STORE` reference that prevents my script from moving forward.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: I tested that code and it appears to work properly. The problem is not in the presented code.

Comment: The provided example works as you want it to.

Comment: thanks @DanD., I'll test further. what should I do with this question, delete?